# Width Toggle Animate in jQuery doesn't work in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Could I be doing wrong, or does the jQuery animate function really not work in Firefox? This works for me in IE8, Opera, and Chrome, but not Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/kdLwg422/

If I really haven't messed up the syntax... What could be the workaround to get this working in Firefox too?

Thank you.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="SearchIcon">Ar!</div>
<div id="LeftPanel"></div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background:orange;
}

#SearchIcon{
    background:yellow;
    height:20px;
    width:40px;
}
#LeftPanel{
    position:absolute;
    vertical-align:top; 
    background:green;
    width:1096px;
    height:588px;
}
```

JS

```
$('#SearchIcon').click(function() {

        event.preventDefault();
        var toggleWidth = $("#LeftPanel").width() == 365 ? "1096px" : "365px"; 
        $('#LeftPanel').animate( {'width': toggleWidth}, 300); 


});
```

Comment: What does _not work_ mean? Are there any errors in the console in Firefox?

Comment: The div's width successfully toggles using the jQuery animate function in every browser I've tried except for FireFox. As for checking errors in the console, I don't know how to do that to be honest. (Edit: Oh, just Ctrl+Shift+J?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `event.preventDefault()`.

**EDIT:**

`event` isn't available in the global scope in firefox. By calling it before defining it, you are creating an error, preventing execution of the rest of the method. Just add an event variable into the callback.

```
$('#SearchIcon').click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var toggleWidth = $("#LeftPanel").width() == 365 ? "1096px" : "365px"; 
    $('#LeftPanel').animate( {'width': toggleWidth}, 300); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is `event is not defined`.

Pass in the `event`:

```
$('#SearchIcon').click(function(event) { /* <-- pass in event param */
    var $panel = $("#LeftPanel"),
        toggleWidth = $panel.width() == 365 ? "1096px" : "365px";

    event.preventDefault();
    $panel.animate( {'width': toggleWidth}, 300); 
});
```

... and store your `$("#LeftPanel")` lookup.